# Draw an exisiting ArrayBuffer into a Canvas without copying

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `Uint8ClampedArray` which contains a bitmap. The following works but I want to avoid the copying of the buffer and as I understand `ImageData.set` copies the ArrayBuffer.

```
var mappedBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, offset, length); // Creates a view on the emscripten heap
var imageData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
imageData.data.set(mappedBuffer); // copy here
ctx.putImage(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Is there a way to avoid copying so that the we can directly draw to the canvas without a copy first?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is the creating of `ImageData` manually that now can be used in some browser (intended for workers, but can be used from main thread as well). It takes an existing array with a `Uint8ClampedArray` view on top as argument together with width and height.

Since it takes a view, the underlying `ArrayBuffer` is simply referenced instead of copied (just have in mind that `putImageData()` will always need to copy the data).

```
var iData = new ImageData(clampedArray, width, height);
```

This can then be used with `putImageData()`.

```js
// create custom array view and fill with some random data
var array = new Uint32Array(100*100);
for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) array[i] = 0xff000000|(Math.sin(i*0.0001)*0xffffff);

// create ImageData instance
var iData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(array.buffer), 100, 100);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=100 height=100></canvas>
```